# Power bounded operators

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a separable reflexive Banach space and let $T$ be a power-bounded operator on $X$ ($\sup_n \|T^n\|<\infty$.) Let $S$ be a WOT-limit point of $(T^n)$. Suppose for some $n$ we have $T^n=S$. Does it follow from this that $T^n$ is an idempotent?

Comment: Excuse for my question, but what is a WOT-limit? Maybe you could include the definition of this in the question.

Comment: @matgaio I guess weak operator topology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a counterexample, if I understand the question correctly.

- $X=\mathbb C^2$
- $T(x,y)=(y,x)$
- $S=T$
- $n=1$.

Comment: Why is $S$ a wot limit point of the powers of $T$?

Comment: @YemonChoi The odd powers of $T$ equal to $T$, so the powers contain a constant sub-sequence equal to $T=S$.

Comment: sorry, I had wot limit and wot limit point scrambled in my head, shouldn't read maths while decaffeinated